# URL not getting read correctly by MVC 4 routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have a URL as follows in my MVC 4 application

`http://localhost/ABC/Home/DeleteApp/3000`

and I have configured RouteConfig.cs as follows

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

It goes to the Correct DeleteApp Controller but with the ID value Null. It shows the correct URL when I enable firebug.

What could possibly go wrong?
it debugs and come to here but the id field as null;

```
public void DeleteApp(string id)
    {
        try
        {

             // delete logic
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
             //
        }
    }
```

Comment: Kinda hard to answer this without seeing your controller.

Comment: Please show us the controller:)

Comment: It happens when you type url in address bar or when generate actionlink in view?

Comment: @BenPretorius  I added the controller.

Comment: @x2. no it happens within the application

Comment: if your adress is: `http://localhost/ABC/Home/DeleteApp/3000`

then:

    controller = ABC
    Action= Home
    Id= Delteapp
Or I'm wrong?

Comment: @szpic, nope, you're not wrong. #

Comment: @Kirov, is the `ABC` part suppose to be a subdomain construction? If so, you need to specify it in the routing.

Comment: ABC is the name of the Application  sorry this is my first MVC4 developmenet

Comment: @Kirov, you shouldn't apologize for _not knowing_.

Comment: @Kirov maybe change your project to the default in IIS? Then it should be available at /localhost/ without /ABC/ part?

Comment: it comes as localhost/ABC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibles causes :

-> Check your "id" variable name (must be exactly the same name in the RouteConfig and in the controller action, it is case sensitive)

-> You have other routes mapped before this one that match the pattern

If you have a route mapped as `{controller}/{action}/{something}` and another route mapped as `{controller}/{action}/{something_else}`, when you call the url "Home/DeleteApp/3000", it can't tell if 3000 is "something" or "something_else" so it will take the first match.

To make this working, you have to use "Route Constraints"
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: there was another configuration as named url: "{controller}/{action}/{mobile_num}"

Comment: It use the first route that matches the pattern, your pattern is 
{controller}/{action}/{something}, it can't tell the difference between the "id" and the "mobile_num" so it takes the first that match

Comment: Okay Is it possible to use a regex?

Comment: I think you have to use a route constraint for that but I never used that. See this link for more informations : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it like so:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ABC",
        url: "ABC/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: still the ID field goes as null

Comment: Action link is Home/DeleteApp/30507

Comment: Hi Thank you so much I got the answer from @Gilles

Comment: No Problem. Glad you got it sorted :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have url in this format `http://localhost/ABC` then you will have to modify the route as below by adding ABC to {controller}/{action}/{id} expression.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "ABC/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```